# How to upload files using jwbf?

Tags: java, api, mediawiki, bots

I've been trying to upload an image to my MediaWiki (v 1.19) set up on my localhost. XAMPP and everything else is set up and working. I can perform other actions using the API.

But I've had no luck using any of the FileUpload/Post classes. Since there is nearly not one single explanation on how to do this task in the documentation, I've been trying several things, so this is my code:

```
//The bot i'm using. Works fine for other purposes.
MediaWikiBot b = new MediaWikiBot("http://localhost/");
b.login("Bot", "password");

//The file I want to upload
File f = new File("/home/op/Necro MP FILES/NPC/GIF/Air Screamer.gif");
SimpleFile sf = new SimpleFile(f.getName(), f);
```

But I'm stuck there. I can't find a single method I can use to actually upload the file. I've tried using FileUpload but I can't use it for anything.

```
FileUpload fu = new FileUpload(sf, b);
```

It just builds me a ContentProcessable object, and that would be awesome if this would work:

```
b.performAction(fu);
```

But no luck. I've run out of things to test. I've tried doing a very similar routine using both HttpBot and HttpActionClient, both supposed to work, but same result.

Does anyone have experience and can point me out what I'm missing? I have to upload around 1500 images and it's not a task I'm going to do by hand.

The full reference for jwbf is here: http://jwbf.sourceforge.net/tests/

This is the log the code above yields:

```
16:07:30.837 [main] DEBUG n.s.j.core.actions.HttpActionClient - /index.php?title=Air+Screamer.gif&action=edit&dontcountme=s
16:07:30.838 [main] DEBUG n.s.j.core.actions.HttpActionClient - message (GET FileUpload) is: 
 hostPath : http://localhost
 queryPath: /index.php?title=Air+Screamer.gif&action=edit&dontcountme=s
16:07:31.423 [main] INFO  n.s.j.m.actions.editing.FileUpload - WRITE: Air Screamer.gif
16:07:31.424 [main] DEBUG n.s.j.core.actions.HttpActionClient - /index.php?title=Special:Upload
16:07:31.426 [main] DEBUG n.s.j.core.actions.HttpActionClient - message (POST FileUpload) [continuing req] is: 
 hostPath : http://localhost
 queryPath: /index.php?title=Special:Upload
```

Comment: I don't know anything about jwbf, so I can't help you with your specific issue. But if you're not going to find a solution, you could try using another library for accessing the API (which probably means using another language).

Comment: I can give it about three days, while I work on other issues. I could look up for the documentation in PHP (there's plenty and well-made) but I've never written anything on PHP. Other API's and this one have been a pain, but I got this one to work... so far.

Answer (score 0):

So I messed around with another API that failed at me before and I figured out how to make it work! This one is handy and I don't have to deal with this kind of issues. I now can upload pictures with it within a method!

If anyone's wondering, it is MER-C's work: http://code.google.com/p/wiki-java